# Android ColorPicker is shown as black instead of being colorful

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I want to add colorpicker on an activity in the app that I develop. I won't it with dialog. It will be on the content on the activity. When I touch the surface of colorpicker circle, it will return RGB hex value.

Anyway, there is some code below that supplies the needs I mentioned. When I run the app on Android 4.4.2 with the line - android:minSdkVersion="9" on manifest.xml, I can see the circle clearly. But, when I run the app with the line - android:minSdkVersion="14" on manifest.xml, black and white (mostly black) colorpicker circle is shown on the activity instead of colorful circle. It is also weird that when I touch the circle, it returns right values like colorful circle. For ex. when I touch black, it returns 0XFF000000 (red).

Where is my fault? How can I handle it? Please, help me.

layout xml;

```
...
 <com.(package name).ColourPicker
        android:id="@+id/colourPick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
...
```

java class;

```
public class ColourPicker extends View {
    private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

    private int[] mCoord;
    private float[] mHSV;

    private MainActivity ourContext;

    private static int CENTER_X;
    private static int CENTER_Y;
    private static int HUE_RADIUS;
    private static int INNER_RADIUS;
    private static int PALETTE_RADIUS;

    private static int SAT_RADIUS;

    public boolean colourKnown = false;

    int[] mSpectrumColorsRev = new int[] { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF,
            0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000, };

    Paint mOvalHue;
    Paint mOvalHueInner;

    Paint mOvalSat;
    RectF mRectSat;
    Paint mArcSat;
    Paint mPaintSatTextRect;
    Paint mPaintSatText;

    Paint mPosMarker;
    RectF posMarkerRect1;
    RectF posMarkerRect2;

    Shader shaderA;
    Shader shaderB;
    Shader shaderHue;

    Shader shaderSat;

    public ColourPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        ourContext = (MainActivity) context;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        double scalefactor;

        if (metrics.widthPixels < metrics.heightPixels) {
            scalefactor = 2.5;
        } else {
            scalefactor = 5.5;
        }

        CENTER_X = (int) (1 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                    // / 2);
        CENTER_Y = (int) (1 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                    // / 2);
        HUE_RADIUS = (int) (1 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                        // / 6)
                                                                        // -
                                                                        // (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                        // /
                                                                        // 45);
                                                                        // //110;
        INNER_RADIUS = (int) (0.63 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                            // /
                                                                            // 10.5);
                                                                            // //70;
        PALETTE_RADIUS = (int) (1 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                            // /
                                                                            // 6)
                                                                            // -
                                                                            // (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                            // /
                                                                            // 45);
                                                                            // //110;;
        SAT_RADIUS = (int) (0.60 * (metrics.widthPixels / scalefactor));// (metrics.heightPixels
                                                                        // /
                                                                        // 10.5)
                                                                        // -5;
                                                                        // //65;*/

        mOvalHue = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mOvalHueInner = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        mOvalSat = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRectSat = new RectF(-SAT_RADIUS, -SAT_RADIUS, SAT_RADIUS, SAT_RADIUS);
        mArcSat = new Paint();

        mPosMarker = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        shaderA = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mSpectrumColorsRev, null);
        shaderB = new RadialGradient(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, HUE_RADIUS,
                0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shaderHue = new ComposeShader(shaderA, shaderB, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);

        shaderSat = new RadialGradient(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, SAT_RADIUS,
                0xFF888888, 0xFFFFFFFF, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        // InitialisePaints Paints
        mOvalHue.setShader(shaderHue);
        mOvalHue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mOvalHue.setDither(true);

        mOvalSat.setShader(shaderSat);
        mOvalSat.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mOvalSat.setDither(true);
        mOvalSat.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        mArcSat.setAntiAlias(true);
        mArcSat.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mArcSat.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        mPosMarker.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPosMarker.setStrokeWidth(2);

        mPaintSatTextRect = new Paint();
        mPaintSatTextRect.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaintSatTextRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintSatTextRect.setColor(0XFF000000);

        mPaintSatText = new Paint();
        mPaintSatText.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaintSatText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintSatText.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaintSatText.setTextSize(25);

        mCoord = new int[2];
        mHSV = new float[3];
        mHSV[1] = 1;

        posMarkerRect1 = new RectF(mCoord[0] - 5, mCoord[1] - 5, mCoord[0] + 5,
                mCoord[1] + 5);
        posMarkerRect2 = new RectF(mCoord[0] - 3, mCoord[1] - 3, mCoord[0] + 3,
                mCoord[1] + 3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y);

        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, HUE_RADIUS, mOvalHue);
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, INNER_RADIUS, mOvalHueInner);

        // Sat up
        canvas.drawArc(mRectSat, (float) 182, (float) 176, true, mOvalSat);
        canvas.drawArc(mRectSat, (float) 182, (float) 176, true, mArcSat);

        // Sat down
        canvas.drawArc(mRectSat, (float) 2, (float) 176, true, mOvalSat);
        canvas.drawArc(mRectSat, (float) 2, (float) 176, true, mArcSat);

        canvas.drawRect(-(SAT_RADIUS - 10), 15, (SAT_RADIUS - 10), -15,
                mPaintSatTextRect);

        mPaintSatText.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaintSatText.setTextSize(25);
        String satStr = "Saturation";
        canvas.drawText(satStr, -60, 8, mPaintSatText);

        mPaintSatText.setTextSize(35);
        mPaintSatText.setColor(0xFF000000);
        satStr = "+";
        canvas.drawText(satStr, -8, -30, mPaintSatText);
        satStr = "-";
        canvas.drawText(satStr, -8, 50, mPaintSatText);

        if (colourKnown) {
            posMarkerRect1.set(mCoord[0] - 5, mCoord[1] - 5, mCoord[0] + 5,
                    mCoord[1] + 5);
            posMarkerRect2.set(mCoord[0] - 3, mCoord[1] - 3, mCoord[0] + 3,
                    mCoord[1] + 3);

            mPosMarker.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawOval(posMarkerRect1, mPosMarker);
            mPosMarker.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawOval(posMarkerRect2, mPosMarker);
        }
    }

    // Currently Fixed size
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X * 2, CENTER_Y * 2);
    }

    public void drawPortraite() {
        invalidate();
    }

    // Weighted average between points
    private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
        return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
    }

    // Interpolate colour value between points
    private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
        if (unit <= 0) {
            return colors[0];
        }
        if (unit >= 1) {
            return colors[colors.length - 1];
        }

        float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
        int i = (int) p;
        p -= i;

        // now p is just the fractional part [0...1] and i is the index
        int c0 = colors[i];
        int c1 = colors[i + 1];
        int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
        int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
        int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
        int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);
        System.out.println("the vaient is" + b);
        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    private int round(double x) {
        return (int) Math.round(x);
    }

    public void upDateColorPreivew(byte hue, byte sat) {
        // update hue preview
        float unit = (float) hue / 255;
        if (unit < 0) {
            unit += 1;
        }

        unit = 1 - unit;

        int c = interpColor(mSpectrumColorsRev, unit);
        mArcSat.setColor(c);

        // update sat preview
        mArcSat.setAlpha(sat);

        colourKnown = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!isEnabled())
            return false;

        float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
        float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;

        float angle = (float) java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
        float unit = angle / (2 * PI);

        if (unit < 0) {
            unit += 1;
        }

        // Pin the radius
        float radius = (float) java.lang.Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        if (radius > PALETTE_RADIUS)
            radius = PALETTE_RADIUS;

        if (radius < INNER_RADIUS) {
            // User adjusted saturation
            if (angle < 0) {
                // + Sat
                if ((mHSV[1] + 0.10) <= 1) {
                    mHSV[1] += 0.10;
                } else {
                    mHSV[1] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                // - Sat
                if ((mHSV[1] - 0.10) >= 0) {
                    mHSV[1] -= 0.10;
                } else {
                    mHSV[1] = 0;
                }
            }

            byte hue = (byte) ((mHSV[0] / 360) * 255);
            byte sat = (byte) (mHSV[1] * 254);
            ourContext.sendHueSatChange(hue, sat);

            // update preview
            mArcSat.setAlpha((byte) (mHSV[1] * 254));
        } else {
            // User adjusted hue
            mCoord[0] = round(Math.cos(angle)
                    * (HUE_RADIUS - (HUE_RADIUS - INNER_RADIUS) / 2));
            mCoord[1] = round(Math.sin(angle)
                    * (HUE_RADIUS - (HUE_RADIUS - INNER_RADIUS) / 2));

            int c = interpColor(mSpectrumColorsRev, unit);
            float[] hsv = new float[3];
            Color.colorToHSV(c, hsv);
            mHSV[0] = hsv[0];

            colourKnown = true;

            // Update color
            byte hue = (byte) ((mHSV[0] / 360) * 255);
            byte sat = (byte) (mHSV[1] * 254);
            ourContext.sendHueSatChange(hue, sat);


            // update preview
            mArcSat.setColor(c);
            mArcSat.setAlpha((int) (mHSV[1] * 255));
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. Are you doing this on a device or an emulator?

Comment: @MikeM. It works well on emulator, however on device, it does not work properly. I've solved it with the line - android:hardwareAccelerated="false".

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved the problem with the line below by adding into application tag of manifest.xml;

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Related sentences from the link - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling;

"...If your application uses only standard views and Drawables, turning it on globally should not cause any adverse drawing effects. However, because hardware acceleration is not supported for all of the 2D drawing operations, turning it on might affect some of your custom views or drawing calls."